# 301 redirect (.htaccess) of entire domain to another domain index

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have tried solving this on my own but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

Create a 301 redirect of all URLs (including index) on **subdomain.example.com** to **example.com**.

So for example:

- **subdomain.example.com** redirects to **example.com**
- **subdomain.example.com/blog-post** redirects to **example.com**

This means that I DO NOT want to keep the same URL structure that's used on subdomain.example.com. I just want URLs on the subdomain to point to the index on the example.com. I know that's not the best solution for SEO, but that's how I want it.

I have tried accomplish this using

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
```

but that keeps the URL structure and I don't want that.

So how can I solve this?

Comment: _“but that keeps the URL structure”_ - of course it does, the documentation explicitly says so. RedirectMatch does not have that “issue”, and using mdo_rewrite instead would be another way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

keeps the part of the url.

With redirectMatch you can use regexes and substitution to rewrite your url
e.g.

```
RedirectMatch 301 . https://example.com/
```

where the dot (.) is a match anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve this with a `Redirect` as it appends the  old URL path to new one. You can use `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```